# Transparency of multiple tile layers without colors leaking (phaser.js)

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So I have been using the Chebyshev Distance example from the [Phaser labs](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/tilemap/get-chebyshev-distance), and while this example was using one layer, I happen to be using two, and when i set transparency on them, the colors start leaking into each other, especially on light colors.

[image]

Is there any way to circumvent or get rid of this effect

Comment: What excatly do you mean, with colors are leaking? Which part of the image shows the problem? what excatly are you doing in the code, that makes this problem. Do you have a short code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that you have two layers, one ontop of the other and you are making both transparent *(or only the top one)*, and you don't want that color to pass through, the solution could be to hide the tiles on the bottom layer.

Just check in the *map-tile-loop*, if the tile, where you want to change the alpha, has a tile beneath it, and if so make that background tile transparent.

**Here a small working demo:**
*(The main magic is in the `updateMap` function)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        preload,
        create
    }
};

var player;
var bgLayer;
var point1 = {x: 250, y: 31};

var isLeaking = false;

new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload (){
    this.load.image('tiles', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/tilemaps/tiles/catastrophi_tiles_16.png');
    this.load.tilemapCSV('map', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/tilemaps/csv/catastrophi_level2.csv');
}

function create () {

    this.add.text(50, 1, ' <- Background is visible, if no tiles are ontop')
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setDepth(100)
        .setStyle({fontFamily: 'Arial'});
        
    this.infoText = this.add.text(10, 20, 'Click to toggle leaking: on')
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setDepth(100)
        .setStyle({fontFamily: 'Arial'});
        
    // Just creating image for second layer tiles //
    let graphics = this.make.graphics();
    
    graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 16, 16);
    graphics.generateTexture('tiles2', 16, 16);
    // Just creating image for second layer tiles //
    
            
    let map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'map', tileWidth: 16, tileHeight: 16 });
    let tileset = map.addTilesetImage('tiles');
    let tileset2 = map.addTilesetImage('tiles2');
    
    
    bgLayer = map.createBlankLayer('background', tileset2);
    bgLayer.fill(0);
    
    let fgLayer = map.createLayer(0, tileset, 0, 0);
    
    // Just to show that the Background is still show if not Tile is covering
    fgLayer.removeTileAt(0, 0);
    fgLayer.removeTileAt(1, 0);
    fgLayer.removeTileAt(2, 0);

    player = this.add.rectangle(point1.x, point1.y, 5, 5, 0xffffff, .5)
                .setOrigin(.5);
                
    this.input.on('pointerdown', () => {
        isLeaking = !isLeaking;
        this.infoText.setText( `Click to toggle leaking: ${isLeaking?'off':'on'}` )
        updateMap(map);
    });

    updateMap(map);
}

function updateMap (map) {
    
    let originPoint1 = map.getTileAtWorldXY(point1.x, point1.y);
    
    console.info(map.layers.sort((a,b) => b.depth - a.depth))

    map.forEachTile(function (tile) {
        var dist = Phaser.Math.Distance.Chebyshev(
            originPoint1.x,
            originPoint1.y,
            tile.x,
            tile.y
        );
        
        let bgTile = bgLayer.getTileAt(tile.x, tile.y, false)
        let hideOnlyTheseTiles = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]; // Indexes to hide
        if( !isLeaking ){   
            if(hideOnlyTheseTiles.indexOf(bgTile.index) > -1){ // here yopu can select the 
              bgTile.setAlpha(0);
            }
        } else{
            bgTile.setAlpha(1);
        }
        
        tile.setAlpha(1 - 0.09 * dist);
    });

}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to go for specific tiles?, As I have Some background tiles I would like to see, and some I would not

Comment: @VatsaPandey sure you could just check the [index](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Tilemaps.Tile.html#index__anchor) of the `bgTile` is it is the type you need / want.

Comment: Like check in the function to see if there is a tile beneath the current tile

Comment: @VatsaPandey exactly, I updated the example to showcase this.