# Update Tiles After editing them (Phaser.js)

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a tilemap which is editable in game, and a lighting system from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75503347/transparency-of-multiple-tile-layers-without-colors-leaking-phaser-js) I Encounter the issue of having the tiles underneath, the sky, go black, as they were removed by placed tiles, or when premade tiles were removed, it goes black, Is there any way to circumvent this?

[image: Blackness]

CODE

```js
this.input.on("pointerdown", () => {
      if (this.shiftKey.isDown) {
        // add to inventory
        var tile = this.worldLayer.getTileAtWorldXY(
          this.gameState.worldPoint.x,
          this.gameState.worldPoint.y
        );

        if (tile == null) {
          return;
        } else {
          var item = indexInventory(tile.index);
          if (this.gameState.inventory.indexOf(item) == -1) {
            this.gameState.inventory.push(item);
            this.gameState.inventory.push(1);
            console.log(this.gameState.inventory);
            return;
          } else if (this.gameState.inventory.indexOf(item) != -1) {
            this.gameState.inventory[
              this.gameState.inventory.indexOf(item) + 1
            ] =
              this.gameState.inventory[
                this.gameState.inventory.indexOf(item) + 1
              ] + 1;
            console.log(this.gameState.inventory);
            // break block
            this.worldLayer.removeTileAtWorldXY(
              this.gameState.worldPoint.x,
              this.gameState.worldPoint.y
            );
            this.updateMap();
            return;
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the structure and your preference there are several ways here the two quick options:

1. Instead of using the function `this.worldLayer.removeTileAtWorldXY` you could use `replaceByIndex` and set th sky-index *([link to documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Tilemaps.TilemapLayer.html#replaceByIndex__anchor))*
2. Instead of using the function `this.worldLayer.removeTileAtWorldXY` you could use `putTilesAt`, where as you would have to *put* the sky tile. *([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Tilemaps.TilemapLayer.html#putTilesAt__anchor))*